# SQL add values of different rows with same ID

Tags: sql

Query:

```
SELECT code, duration 
FROM table1
```

results in

| code | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 234 | 3 |
| 345 | 2 |
| 345 | 3 |
| 456 | 4 |
| 567 | 5 |
| 567 | 6 |
| 567 | 1 |

I would like to add the durations of the same code and display results as here

| code | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 234 | 3 |
| 345 | 5 |
| 456 | 4 |
| 567 | 12 |

but I don't know where to start with this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` together with `SUM`. When using `GROUP BY`, [aggregate functions](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-aggregate-functions/) (such as `SUM`) will return the output of the function as if every value in the specified column for the entire group was passed to it. In this case you can tell it to run on `duration`.

```
SELECT code, SUM(duration) as TotalDuration FROM table1 GROUP BY code
```

Answer (score 3):

you use aggregation function `SUM`

```
SELECT code, SUM(duration) FROM table1 GROUP BY code
```

Comment: ah, the group by keyword, obviously